# Create mobile framework for multiple platforms

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, mobile

Hey I've been researching the javascript/jquery side of developing applications for multiple mobile platforms. I came across this framework:

http://www.u360mobile.com/

Can someone kindly explain to me how something of this sort is built? In other words what are the technologies/programming languages/frameworks required for building a customisable mobile app? Thanks in advance

Comment: [phonegap](http://phonegap.com) should enable you to do this. Its opensource so you can have a look at how they did it

Answer (score 0):

if your familiar with ruby, you can have a look at it :

http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/RhoMobile+Suite/Rhodes